# How to remove an old OS entry from grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

So, I was trying to install Arch in my system, which already had a dual-boot with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10 installed. The installation went wrong, so I deleted both root and swap partitions from Arch. I had some problems first because my computer was using Arch's grub installation to boot, so I was always entering in grub recovery mod, which I fixer after changing boot order by putting Ubuntu on top again.

My problem is even though I run `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu terminal, at grub menu, the Arch option is still there, with its advanced options. I tried to delete the `arch_boot` folder from `/boot/efi/EFI` directory but it didn't change.

How can I get rid of this? I want to try to make an another Arch installation, but I get the feeling that this entry at grub menu will disturb me. Then, what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should remove the folder in ESP and entry in UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi But a new install will probably just overwrite old entries. /boot/efi/EFI folder is mounted read only in Ubuntu when booted. Older versions used defaults which was read/write.http://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer?noredirect=1#comment1197619_794725

Comment: I've just installed Arch again, and it's old entry doesn't work, as I expected. And my Ubuntu's grub can't detect it, no matter how many times I run `grub-install` and `grub-update`.

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I kinda solved my problem. I'll make an answer to tell what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's what I did:
I had the idea to generate another `grub.cfg` using the following command at terminal:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

It just gave me a different error when I tried to boot in Arch. It couldn't detect its kernel. So I put Arch on top of the boot order again and executed the same command there. This time, it detected Windows 10 installation(which was weird, because it didn't detected it first time I ran this command when I was configuring Arch's boot loader). Now Arch's grub is working fine, except by the fact that when I select Ubuntu at the menu, it gives me this annoying message for some seconds before it boots:

```
Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
```

But I guess the topic problem is now solved.

Answer (score 1):

Re-install Grub

```
sudo grub-install path/to/root/disk
```

Grub auto-detects operative systems during installation. I think it will also detect outside the disk you install it on, Like if you have a Live USB plugged that is not the booted system it will include it too.

I have mine in /dev/sda

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Open Disks app and look for the partition that shows **(Bootable)**:

[image]

[Live CD installation Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lod8sRb_6I)

Comment: It doesn't. I've already tried this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to remove the Windows option : removed Microsoft directory (rm -r) from the /boot/efi/EFI/ directory, and updated grub as suggested in the previous answers.
Windows entry is gone : maybe a bit messy but worked fine.