# How to avoid seeing GRUB menu after replacing windows 10 with Ubuntu (Ubuntu is the only OS installed)

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I replaced Windows 10 with Ubuntu 16.04 (now Ubuntu is the only OS installed), but every time I turn on my laptop, I still have to choose which OS to use in GRUB. It's not automatically loading Ubuntu, although when I choose Ubuntu it works fine. Is there any way I can make it automatically load Ubuntu? My laptop uses UEFI.

[image: it shows like this]

Comment: Both UEFI & grub are boot managers, or they show a menu. So it depends on what you are seeing. Some systems only want to boot a Windows by name UEFI entry. What brand/model system? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer/795341#795341 which may be all you need.

Comment: i've just edited my question, add image to choose OS

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer/795341#795341 and this except use Windows entries not Ubuntu entries: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 1):

If you're not comfortable with editing configuration files, then I'd suggest installing `Grub Customizer`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Go to `General settings` tab. Then set the `Boot default entry after` field to `0`. And press `Save` as shown:

[image]

Please don't change anything else, as it may break your system.