# Uninstall grub2 when booting without secure boot (tried everything, nothing worked)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I used ubuntu and windows in dual boot and deleted ubuntu so I ended up still having grub2. When I install secure boot this prevents grub2 from starting and I can boot into windows. When I disable secure boot (for example to boot a liveCD of ubuntu) it starts the grub2 command line (I think it is emergency mode) and I cant boot anything. I tried everything:
I used a windows 10 repair dvd and used bootrec - didnt work
I used several programs including easybcd, mbrfix, dbr, etc. - didnt work
I tried using the bootsect in the cmd - didnt work
I tried using grub2 to boot windows - didnt work

What else can I do to get rid of it? If you need anymore information feel free to ask. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Comment: This is no duplicate I read that thread before and tried everything they wrote (see question) but nothing worked, so please dont mark it as a duplicate!

Comment: If UEFI, you should just be able to set Windows as first in UEFI boot order. But you may want to remove ubuntu entries from UEFI NVRAM/menu and /EFI/ubuntu folder from ESP - efi system partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi or: https://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer/795341#795341

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I am accessing my efi folder and it shows 252,4mb used but when I open it the folder/drive is empty. I am currently only able to use windows

Comment: Ah I figuered it out. @oldfred if you want to post your comment as an answer I will mark it as the one which solved my question. If anyone has the same problem contact me. Thank to everbody paricipating in this thread.

Comment: @llovescience Did you see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader/869888#869888) answer?

Comment: @pixelherodev Thank you for your comment. Yes this was the answer that eventually fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If UEFI boot, you should just be able to set Windows as first in UEFI boot order.

But you may want to remove ubuntu entries from UEFI NVRAM/menu and /EFI/ubuntu folder from ESP - efi system partition.

[How do I remove "Ubuntu" in the bios boot menu? (UEFI)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi)

OR:

[Can I remove Windows Boot Manager from dedicated Ubuntu computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer/795341#795341)