# delete windows 10 from dual boot completely

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

i just made a decision and deleted windows partition 
but now i have windows 10 in grub menu although i updated grub
my windows 10 and ubuntu both of them installed as EFI systems 
and i know both of them had a partition they used
but i dont know how to delete windows boot files to delete windows completely from grub and my UEFI firmware

[this the screenshot from gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVRbT.png)

as you see /dev/sda2 is efi partition
what should i do?

Comment: Unless it is really bugging you it might be better just to leave it, it won't hurt anything.   Making a small boo boo removing it, might make a big mess of things.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer & Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the Windows entry in grub boot menu is that there is still an EFI entry for it in the EFI partition, e.g. a folder `/dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft`. If the Windows partition has already been deleted, then the Microsoft folder in the EFI partition can also be removed.

After removing the obsolete Microsoft from the EFI partition and running `update-grub` the Windows entry should disappear from grub boot menu.