# So basically I dual booted ubuntu with win 10 last year now I want to make my laptop fully ubuntu how to do that?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I don't want to loose my ubuntu dual boot data I don't care about the windows data is there any way to make my pc fully ubuntu without deleting the existing ubuntu dual boot data

Comment: Format the Windows drive with `gparted` and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: While you have dual booted for a while I would still suggest a full backup of Windows. Users often come back after they have found one app or game that only works or works well in Windows and want to reinstall Windows. If UEFI you can also remove UEFI boot entry & /EFI/Microsoft folder in ESP. Do not keep any NTFS partitions, backup & convert to ext4. You cannot repair NTFS from Linux. https://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer

Answer (score 0):

### ***`SUBJECT TO DATA LOSS`***

First of all check on what drive is windows on
it may be sda1 or sda2 or any sda`x` then

1. Get a pendrive
2. Download the Gparted iso from https://gparted.org/download.php
3. And then download Unetbootin and make the pendrive bootable with the gparted iso you downloaded
4. insert the pendrive and then reboot, before it shows the grub, press F12 or Fn + F12. it may be different for your computer or laptop.
5. boot from the pendrive and select GPARTED LIVE option
6. then select don't touch keymap
7. then select language, if english press enter
8. You can now begin using the GParted application.
9. right click and delete the sda on which windows is located. It may be sda1 or 2 or anything
10. Now you get the unallocated the space (WINDOWS RIP)
11. if you want you can right click the UBUNTU partition and select resize to increase the size by merging the unallocated space with ubuntu installation
12. now exit

Comment: It can be done from within Ubuntu.

Comment: no it can't be done

Comment: my answer is about merging deleted windows space with ubuntu also, so it can't be done when ubuntu is mounted