# How to remove dual boot and select Ubuntu as the primary and only os deleting windows

Tags: dual-boot

My question is about boot
I'm totally new to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu from a usb drive. Now I want to completely wipe out windows from my laptop and run ubuntu as my only os. And another thing Ubuntu shows only 9 gb of memory useable but my ssd is 1000 gb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove Windows but keep Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784/how-do-i-remove-windows-but-keep-ubuntu)

Comment: Back up Windows. And with any major change backup Ubuntu.  We get many who want to erase Windows but later find one app or game that only works in Windows. Post this `sudo parted -l` https://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer & https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions