# Unable to prevent Windows 10 boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows-10

Installed Ubuntu from DVD selecting remove Windows. When booting the PC it still boots to Windows.  How to get it to boot to Ubuntu?  Ver. 20.04. Windows 10. Used the default partitions for the install. Appears to be one partition for the whole drive. 400gb. Installed from a USB DVD drive as could not get USB thumb drive or older (installed) DVD to be recognised. ASUS Mboard and external DVD drive. Changed boot device setting to hard drive.

Comment: Are you sure you only have one disk?  Maybe you installed linux on the wrong one.

Comment: If UEFI install, the old boot entries are kept in UEFI and you may have boot files in ESP - efi system partition. If totally removing Windows you want to houseclean ESP & UEFI entries. Older but valid: [Remove Windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer?noredirect=1#comment1197619_794725)

Comment: Do have two discs,  but it boots Windows whichever I select.  I just used the default download from the Ubuntu site - is that a UEFI install? Sorry, new to Linux.  Perhaps I should reformat both discs, since Windows is still working and start again. But presumably Win won’t let me reformat its own disc. How do I do that? Just delete everything obviously Windows related until it gives-up and then reinstall Ubuntu? Thnx.

Comment: Maybe you install Ubuntu to the second disk?  Try the efI menu (some key at power-up to allow choice of OS) to select ubuntu (if present). See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to wrong disk. Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Comment: Thanks @Nmath - I will try to use “Disks” after a boot from DVD to erase  both discs and reinstall.