# How to remove Windows efi entry from Grub after drive migration

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Windows on a new SSD and then migrated the SSD containing Ubuntu installation, to the one which had Windows previously installed on it.

The issue is that Grub still detects the old Windows efi entry and adds it to the boot menu, along with the new Windows entry.

Is there anyway to delete the old and useless entry in Grub?

I tried update-grub, but still finds the entry.

Running on Ubuntu 22.04.1 x86_64.

Comment: If you also have Windows booting be careful not to delete what it needs. If UEFI boot, you have an UEFI boot entry. And you have in the ESP - efi system partition a /EFI/Windows folder with Windows boot files. I believe grub2's os-prober finds those files. Typically the ESP is locked by mounting with umask=0077 in fstab to prevent corruption. I normally turn off os-prober and only add the entries I want into 40_custom. https://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer