# Installing Ubuntu alongside pre-installed Windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu on my new laptop that came with Windows 8 pre-installed. Here's what I have done:
 - created bootable flash drive with Ubuntu installer
 - created a partition (ext4) using half of my total hard drive space (around 225 GB)
The problem I encounter is that Ubuntu is not detecting any OS, which in this case would be my Windows 8. I think I may be able to just manually choose my newly created partition, but I am still hesitant to proceed because of this. I'm not sure exactly what I should do. I want to install it permanently anyway, but I was under the impression that there would be an option for "Try Ubuntu" and I only see "Install Ubuntu", and I don't want it to somehow mess up my current OS, as I want to be able to boot into either one. I noticed that people had said in other places to disable quickboot in the BIOS, and I haven't figured out how to do this. I disabled Fast Startup, but I am pretty sure that isn't the same thing.

---

I went ahead and installed, and it seems to be working fine. I was wondering though, I only created the root abd swap partitions, and I noticed that it was suggested there be 3, root, home and swap, with home being the disk for most if the memory. should i format the partition, create the home partition and then reinstall?

Comment: There are hundreds on tutorials on youtube, for this. (Dual boot windows and ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this article](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) to see how to **Try Ubuntu**.

1. **Make a backup of your Windows Installation and make sure you create a Windows USB stick** (unless you have a Windows installation
   disk) alongwith your Ubuntu USB drive **before going further**.
2. Secondly, yes you can install `Ubuntu` manually. Make sure that you
   **do not modify the partition containing Windows**. All of this is reversible, so don't worry.
3. If, after installation, GRUB sees Windows, you're all set, otherwise
   try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation).
4. If GRUB doesn't see Windows, you can still try [updating
   manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210914/grub-does-not-show-a-windows-8-option-after-dual-boot).
5. If you want to go back, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343432/how-to-uninstall-ubuntu-and-grub-from-pre-installed-windows-8).

Answer (score 0):

it is simple and easy
use "wubi.exe " which is easily available on Ubuntu website
copy "wubi.exe" in C: Drive >> insert/ Plug  Ubuntu DVD/Bootable Flesh Drive and Run "wubi.exe" it will ask user Name and Password to you give it and click on install so simple

FYI  use this Link:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Comment: Wubi doesn't support Windows 8!